# Responding in a language other than the user language (Actions on Google)

Tags: actions-on-google

I am working on a bilingual application targeting Google Home, and the program needs to be able to correctly enunciate responses in a language other than English, even when the user request is in English.

I cannot find an API flag to set the TTS language for individual responses. Is there any mechanism for this?

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, although there are hints about how it might be done in the future. (To be clear - there is no guarantee they will support it this way, or support such a feature at all.)

[SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.1) supports the `<voice>` tag, which includes a `languages` attribute. Although Google's [SSML documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) does not mention it, the `<voice>` tag is available, and some attributes (but not the `languages` attribute) do work. Given this hidden feature, it seems possible that multi-lingual support may be handled this way in the future.

In the meantime, you may wish to use the SSML `<audio>` tag to play a pre-recorded or otherwise generated clip.

Note that this doesn't address *input* in a different language than the locale the user has set.

Comment: Thanks! That'll get me halfway there, at any rate. I'll keep looking for a lookaround for bilingual input.